# unable to execute command with find statement in solaris

Tags: bash, unix, awk, posix, solaris

the script is running normally on ubuntu Linux and i can call bin_packing.awk, but when I try to run it on unix solaris I'm getting an error:

> ```
> find: bad option -printf
> find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
> awk: syntax error near line 1
> awk: bailing out near line 1
> ```

this is the script that works on ubuntu

```
$ find . -type f -iname '*pdf' -printf "%s %p\n" \
  | awk -v c=100000 -f bin_packing.awk
```

i have tried this and it works but without | awk...part

```
 $ find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -print | perl -lne '$,=" "; @s=stat $_; print $s[7],$_' \
  | awk -v c=100000 -f bin_packing.awk
```

Comment: Correct, `-printf` is a GNU feature, so it isn't available in non-GNU versions of `find`.

Comment: I don't really know what you expect as an answer here; you can't use GNU-only features with non-GNU versions of find. [BashFAQ #87](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087) is a good place to start re: finding size without GNU tools.

Comment: That said, is your specific version of Solaris new enough to at least have `find -exec ... {} +` (added to the POSIX specification in 2008, IIRC), or is it `-exec ... {} \;` only?

Comment: BTW, to prove my point that any syntax error from `awk` needs to be asked as a completely independent question -- do you get a syntax error from awk with just `awk -v c=100000 -f bin_packing.awk`, and no `find` at all?

Comment: the script is working well in linux the issue is only with Solaris, great now I will ask another question about this point and mention bin_packing.awk , many thanks dear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On modern systems, you can use GNU `stat` or GNU `find` to extract size without needing to do something awful like parse `ls`.

Unfortunately, you're not on a modern system, so it's time to do something awful. Fortunately, size is one of the fields of `ls` that can be semi-reliably parsed (when running it over only one file at a time) as long as you're on a platform that doesn't allow crazy things like usernames with spaces.

```
find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' -exec bash -c '
for name; do
  read -r _ _ _ _ size _ < <(ls -l -- "$name")
  printf "%s %s\n" "$size" "$name"
done
' _ {} + | awk -v c=100000 -f bin_packing.awk
```

If `-exec ... {} +` syntax doesn't work, you can change the `+` to a `\;` to make this slower but more compatible.

Comment: There is _no_ POSIX variant of `stat` available? only the GNU version?

Comment: The GNU version is the only one that allows control over output format. If the output's both uncontrollable and unspecified, it can't be portably parsed.

Comment: after running im getting the below errors: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: What happens if you take out the `| awk` pipeline element at the end? If you still get the error, it sounds like you're running the script with awk instead of running it with a POSIX-y shell.

Comment: i have changed + to /; and replaced -iname to -name but its doesn't work

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't an actionable description. We need *exact* error messages to be able to say anything useful (without actually having a Solaris box to test against). And note that I specified `\;` (aka `';'`), not `/;`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i have changed -iname to -name and neglect | awk ... and its worked  
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec bash -c '
for name; do
  read -r _ _ _ _ size _ < <(ls -l -- "$name")
  printf "%s %s\n" "$size" "$name"
done
' _ {} + |
and if i keep the script it returns
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: sure, but that means an error in the awk script, and you haven't *shown* us the contents of `bin_packing.awk`, so it isn't a part of the question.

Comment: ...frankly, if you have questions about how to change an awk script to work on Solaris, that should be a whole new/different question than how to change the `find` usage, and of course it's a question that will need to include the body of your `bin_packing.awk`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the current version of Solaris you can use `find`'s `-print` option.  For older Solaris, use `gfind` (for GNU find).